# Null Reference Exception - Not Capturing Label Value on Redirect

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a class called UserInfo, which grabs data from the authenticated user on the page, using PrincipalContext.  This work succesfully on page load.  I capture the user's active directory display name, on page load in a label.

Problem:  I would like to redirect to a post page.  The code included works if I do not redirect the user to a different page, which Interent research indicates is because the state is retained.  Moreover, even though I receive the null error in debug mode, the data is actually stored in the database, as expected.  But, when I do try to redirect the user to a new page, presumably the value of the label is lost and this error occurs.  I do not know why the redirect causes the page to reload again, but because the label value is lost my error then becomes a "null reference unhandled by user code."  I have attempted to check for a null value, and to instantiate the class, as several posts have indicated, but when I perform debugging, the error shows up on this line:  "lbRequesterName.Text = userinfo.DisplayName;" So, clearly I am doing something wrong.  Code page and markup below.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            UserInfo userinfo = new UserInfo();

            if (userinfo != null)
            {
                lbRequesterName.Text = userinfo.DisplayName;
            } 
        }

    //Submit data
        protected void btnSubmit_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            insertReg();
        }


        protected void insertReg()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            string strHidRecID = hidRecID.Value;
            if (strHidRecID == "") strHidRecID = "0";

            dt = dataAccessClass.ExecuteDataTable
            (
                "spRegInsert", dataAccessClass.dbName, new SqlParameter[2]
                {
                    new SqlParameter ("@vRequesterName",lbRequesterName.Text),
                    new SqlParameter ("@vRecID", strHidRecID)

                }
            );

            hidRecID.Value = dt.Rows[0]["recID"].ToString();
            Response.Redirect("RegPost.aspx?recID=" + dt.Rows[0]["recID"].ToString());
        }


//Markup
    <asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
<form id="frmInput" runat="server" action="">



<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbRequesterName" Text="Name"></asp:Label>

<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" CssClass="btn" OnClick="btnSubmit_click" Text="Submit"/>

<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hidRecID"/>
```

Comment: You are creating a new instance of `UserInfo` when you write `UserInfo userinfo = new UserInfo();`, which means it is not null (hence why it enters into the `if (userinfo != null)`. Then you try to read the `userinfo.DisplayName` from this newly created object. This the display name of the new instance you just created -- it would only contain any value that you assigned from the `UserInfo` constructor.

Comment: Hmm.  I am not sure I understand - is there a way to write this so that I am able to either retain whatever was assigned when i created the object, or somehow assign it somewhere else?  To me, it is odd that this error only fires when i add the response.redirect line.  Not sure I understand why it's going back to the !postback line to begin with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that my webconfig file did not authenticate the user on the post page.  I added this line in web config to allow authenticated users, and the rest of the code worked:

```
<location path="RegPost.aspx">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```